# Fermilab's results and a fifth force

Tags: forces, particle-physics, cosmology, dark-matter

On today's news, it says that Fermilab have done measurements on the spin of muons and that they are measured to wobble faster than expected according to current physics theories.

Apparently this may turn physics 'on it's head' and suggests that there might be a fifth force.

What measurements have been made?

and

Why do the measurements suggest the need for a fifth force?

Here is an extract from the BBC article

https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/56643677

> "The Muon g-2 experiment involves sending the particles around a
> 14-metre ring and then applying a magnetic field. Under the current
> laws of physics, encoded in a theory known as the Standard Model, this
> should make the muons wobble at a certain rate. Instead, the
> scientists found that muons wobbled at a faster rate than expected.
> They say this might be caused by a force of nature that's completely
> new to science.  Fermilab is America's premier particle physics lab.
>
> No one yet knows what this potential new force does, other than
> influence muon particles. Theoretical physicists believe that it might
> also be associated with an as-yet undiscovered sub-atomic particle.
> There is more than one concept for what this hypothetical particle
> might be. One is called a leptoquark, another is the Z' boson (Z-prime
> boson)."

Does anyone know any more details?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon_g-2

Comment: The wikipedia article must have been added or updated today, looks interesting, thanks.

Comment: [PRL](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.126.141801).  Fifth force? Give us a [break](https://www.symmetrymagazine.org/sites/default/files/images/standard/g-2.png).

Comment: The basic [facts](https://www.anl.gov/article/field-guides-argonne-scientists-bolster-evidence-of-undiscovered-particles-or-forces-in-muon-g2).  “There is something fascinating about science. One gets such wholesale returns of conjecture out of such a trifling investment of fact.” Mark Twain.

Comment: Good quote, but apparently the evidence for some strange physics has grown stronger with the recent results.

Comment: It is the slap-happy "strange physics" that's being lampooned, not the "discrepancy" from tricky conventional expectations.

Comment: Perhaps you're right, maybe "reports of the death of the standard model have been greatly exaggerated"...

Comment: there are some articles at https://phys.org/physics-news/ which talk about this.

Comment: I'd suggest reaching out and asking the authors of the paper. Try and find the most junior coauthor or someone within their group via their institutional website. Don't hold your breath though, invoking a new force every time the Standard Model is a little out seems a bit much.