# Has there been any progress on resolving the $g-2$ experiment discrepancy from 2021 with the standard model?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model

In April 2021, the physics community was surprised by the [$g-2$ experiment](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/627875/) results and how it disagrees with the standard model.

Where can I find more progress that has been done on the issue?

Comment: The [Particle Data Group review](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2022/reviews/contents_sports.html) ([pdf link](https://pdg.lbl.gov/2022/reviews/rpp2022-rev-g-2-muon-anom-mag-moment.pdf)) was updated in August 2021. A research strategy would be to look for recent papers which cite [the April 2021 measurement](https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2104.03281).

Comment: thanks that's helpful!